# org-mode remote R not working with org 8.0.7

Tags: r, emacs, remote-access, org-mode

I have an org file with R source blocks. Now I want to execute some or actually all of them remotely on my server. I followed the set up from the org manual and am using =dir:= like in the example below (for obvious reasons I'm not showing my username or the server name; I can however connect without password, so ssh setup is OK):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :dir /xxx@xxx: :exports both
  system("hostname")
#+END_SRC
```

when I evaluate this with C-c C-c I get the following:

```
executing R code block...
Tramp: Encoding region using function `base64-encode-region'...done
Tramp: Decoding region into remote file /ssh:xxx@xxx:/var/folders/2m/4d7t6kwx0tn2p6blmf3l7_kh0000gn/T/R-30000dMv...done
byte-code: Couldn't write region to `/ssh:xxx@xxx:/var/folders/2m/4d7t6kwx0tn2p6blmf3l7_kh0000gn/T/R-30000dMv', decode using `base64 -d -i >%s' failed
```

apparently there is some problem with the remote folders, since on my server I do not have the permission to write to /var, or actually /var/folders does not exist, it exists only locally on my Mac.

I get similar error messages when I try to use sh:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /xxx@xxx: :export both
hostname
#+END_SRC
```

Does anybody have a solution for this? or an alternative way to execute the R-code on a remote machine?

my Emacs version is 24.3, org 8.0.7

thanks in advance for any replies!

**Update:**

I found the following post [emacs org-mode mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2012-11/msg00414.html) that seems to be related to my problem. Indeed org seems to use the wrong file names if code is executed remotely. I don't know how to fix that, or if I can find a solution myself...

**Update:**

An alternative way to execute R-code remotely is the following:

Start a remote ssh connection with "M-x ssh", connect to your server, start R there and call "M-x ess-remote" in the remote buffer. Now, when specifying name of the remote R buffer as "session" it will execute the code remotely:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :exports both :results output :session *ssh xxx*
  system( "hostname" )
#+END_SRC
```

this will return the host name of the server (note, the "xxx" above will be your server name).
**Important** ":results value" will lead to the same problem with the temporary files, only ":results output" seems to work by now.

**Update and solution:**

So the `:results output` is the way to go. This works also for the `:dir` remote code execution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first test if Tramp works on your Emacs.

Comment: You're right. I should have done that. Well, now I did and tried to open a file on the server using tramp. The file content is also nicely shown in Emacs, but Emacs hangs after that. So I have to figure out what is happening... I already tried all things in [link](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode#toc3) without success. I'm trying to connect to a server running CentOS 6 from my Mac (10.8.4 Mountain Lion).

Comment: It seems to be Mac related... I've tested it to connect from a unix to a unix and it's working there.

Comment: Update: ECB was the culprit. I found that solution: [link](http://emacs.1067599.n5.nabble.com/ECB-2-40-ecb-tramp-causes-emacs-to-hang-td235473.html). Now I can open files in my Emacs using tramp. So tramp is definitely working, but I still cannot execute code from org mode remotely.